# Active Admin: add admin user works local but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, development-environment, production-environment

I have Ruby on Rails 5.2 API app with modifications so that active admin will work on the app.
I try to add more admin users in the Admin User resource (in the app itself). When I run the server locally, it's working but on production it's not.
I'm using HatchBox to deploy production.

EDIT:
this is the error I get- 
[image]

EDIT 2:
This is the error I get in the server after trying to add new admin user:

```js
F, [2019-02-27T08:30:47.881964 #27639] FATAL -- : [4b9ba7db-8892-4b0c-8b27-db5e6b73d0e2] app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_devise_mailer_reset_password_instructions_html_erb___3525588426361625838_70305521708780'
[4b9ba7db-8892-4b0c-8b27-db5e6b73d0e2] app/models/admin_user.rb:12:in `block in <class:AdminUser>'
```

It's said something do with this file in line 5 but I don't know what. Locally it's working so I don't see any problem that in production it won't work:

```js
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

This is my admin_users.rb and active_admin.rb:

**admin_users.rb:**

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  filter :email
  filter :current_sign_in_at
  filter :sign_in_count
  filter :created_at

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

**active_admin.rb:**

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  # == Site Title
  #
  # Set the title that is displayed on the main layout
  # for each of the active admin pages.
  #
  config.site_title = "Labguru Academy Admin"

  # Set the link url for the title. For example, to take
  # users to your main site. Defaults to no link.
  #
  # config.site_title_link = "/"

  # Set an optional image to be displayed for the header
  # instead of a string (overrides :site_title)
  #
  # Note: Aim for an image that's 21px high so it fits in the header.
  #
  # config.site_title_image = "logo.png"

  # == Default Namespace
  #
  # Set the default namespace each administration resource
  # will be added to.
  #
  # eg:
  #   config.default_namespace = :hello_world
  #
  # This will create resources in the HelloWorld module and
  # will namespace routes to /hello_world/*
  #
  # To set no namespace by default, use:
  #   config.default_namespace = false
  #
  # Default:
  # config.default_namespace = :admin
  #
  # You can customize the settings for each namespace by using
  # a namespace block. For example, to change the site title
  # within a namespace:
  #
  #   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     admin.site_title = "Custom Admin Title"
  #   end
  #
  # This will ONLY change the title for the admin section. Other
  # namespaces will continue to use the main "site_title" configuration.

  # == User Authentication
  #
  # Active Admin will automatically call an authentication
  # method in a before filter of all controller actions to
  # ensure that there is a currently logged in admin user.
  #
  # This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
  # within the application controller.
  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!

  # == User Authorization
  #
  # Active Admin will automatically call an authorization
  # method in a before filter of all controller actions to
  # ensure that there is a user with proper rights. You can use
  # CanCanAdapter or make your own. Please refer to documentation.
  # config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter

  # In case you prefer Pundit over other solutions you can here pass
  # the name of default policy class. This policy will be used in every
  # case when Pundit is unable to find suitable policy.
  # config.pundit_default_policy = "MyDefaultPunditPolicy"

  # You can customize your CanCan Ability class name here.
  # config.cancan_ability_class = "Ability"

  # You can specify a method to be called on unauthorized access.
  # This is necessary in order to prevent a redirect loop which happens
  # because, by default, user gets redirected to Dashboard. If user
  # doesn't have access to Dashboard, he'll end up in a redirect loop.
  # Method provided here should be defined in application_controller.rb.
  # config.on_unauthorized_access = :access_denied

  # == Current User
  #
  # Active Admin will associate actions with the current
  # user performing them.
  #
  # This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
  # (within the application controller) to return the currently logged in user.
  config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user

  # == Logging Out
  #
  # Active Admin displays a logout link on each screen. These
  # settings configure the location and method used for the link.
  #
  # This setting changes the path where the link points to. If it's
  # a string, the strings is used as the path. If it's a Symbol, we
  # will call the method to return the path.
  #
  # Default:
  config.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path

  # This setting changes the http method used when rendering the
  # link. For example :get, :delete, :put, etc..
  #
  # Default:
  # config.logout_link_method = :get

  # == Root
  #
  # Set the action to call for the root path. You can set different
  # roots for each namespace.
  #
  # Default:
  # config.root_to = 'dashboard#index'

  # == Admin Comments
  #
  # This allows your users to comment on any resource registered with Active Admin.
  #
  # You can completely disable comments:
  config.comments = false
  #
  # You can change the name under which comments are registered:
  config.comments_registration_name = 'AdminComment'
  #
  # You can change the order for the comments and you can change the column
  # to be used for ordering:
  # config.comments_order = 'created_at ASC'
  #
  # You can disable the menu item for the comments index page:
  config.comments_menu = false
  #
  # You can customize the comment menu:
  # config.comments_menu = { parent: 'Admin', priority: 1 }

  # == Batch Actions
  #
  # Enable and disable Batch Actions
  #
  config.batch_actions = true

  # == Controller Filters
  #
  # You can add before, after and around filters to all of your
  # Active Admin resources and pages from here.
  #
  # config.before_action :do_something_awesome

  # == Localize Date/Time Format
  #
  # Set the localize format to display dates and times.
  # To understand how to localize your app with I18n, read more at
  # https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib%2Fi18n%2Fbackend%2Fbase.rb#L52
  #
  config.localize_format = :long

  # == Setting a Favicon
  #
  # config.favicon = 'favicon.ico'

  # == Meta Tags
  #
  # Add additional meta tags to the head element of active admin pages.
  #
  # Add tags to all pages logged in users see:
  #   config.meta_tags = { author: 'My Company' }

  # By default, sign up/sign in/recover password pages are excluded
  # from showing up in search engine results by adding a robots meta
  # tag. You can reset the hash of meta tags included in logged out
  # pages:
  #   config.meta_tags_for_logged_out_pages = {}

  # == Removing Breadcrumbs
  #
  # Breadcrumbs are enabled by default. You can customize them for individual
  # resources or you can disable them globally from here.
  #
  # config.breadcrumb = false

  # == Create Another Checkbox
  #
  # Create another checkbox is disabled by default. You can customize it for individual
  # resources or you can enable them globally from here.
  #
  # config.create_another = true

  # == Register Stylesheets & Javascripts
  #
  # We recommend using the built in Active Admin layout and loading
  # up your own stylesheets / javascripts to customize the look
  # and feel.
  #
  # To load a stylesheet:
  #   config.register_stylesheet 'my_stylesheet.css'
  #
  # You can provide an options hash for more control, which is passed along to stylesheet_link_tag():
  #   config.register_stylesheet 'my_print_stylesheet.css', media: :print
  #
  # To load a javascript file:
  #   config.register_javascript 'my_javascript.js'

  # == CSV options
  #
  # Set the CSV builder separator
  # config.csv_options = { col_sep: ';' }
  #
  # Force the use of quotes
  # config.csv_options = { force_quotes: true }

  # == Menu System
  #
  # You can add a navigation menu to be used in your application, or configure a provided menu
  #
  # To change the default utility navigation to show a link to your website & a logout btn
  #
  #   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
  #       menu.add label: "My Great Website", url: "http://www.mygreatwebsite.com", html_options: { target: :blank }
  #       admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu
  #     end
  #   end
  #
  # If you wanted to add a static menu item to the default menu provided:
  #
  #   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     admin.build_menu :default do |menu|
  #       menu.add label: "My Great Website", url: "http://www.mygreatwebsite.com", html_options: { target: :blank }
  #     end
  #   end

  # == Download Links
  #
  # You can disable download links on resource listing pages,
  # or customize the formats shown per namespace/globally
  #
  # To disable/customize for the :admin namespace:
  #
  #   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #
  #     # Disable the links entirely
  #     admin.download_links = false
  #
  #     # Only show XML & PDF options
  #     admin.download_links = [:xml, :pdf]
  #
  #     # Enable/disable the links based on block
  #     #   (for example, with cancan)
  #     admin.download_links = proc { can?(:view_download_links) }
  #
  #   end

  # == Pagination
  #
  # Pagination is enabled by default for all resources.
  # You can control the default per page count for all resources here.
  #
  # config.default_per_page = 30
  #
  # You can control the max per page count too.
  #
  # config.max_per_page = 10_000

  # == Filters
  #
  # By default the index screen includes a "Filters" sidebar on the right
  # hand side with a filter for each attribute of the registered model.
  # You can enable or disable them for all resources here.
  #
  # config.filters = true
  #
  # By default the filters include associations in a select, which means
  # that every record will be loaded for each association.
  # You can enabled or disable the inclusion
  # of those filters by default here.
  #
  # config.include_default_association_filters = true

  # == Footer
  #
  # By default, the footer shows the current Active Admin version. You can
  # override the content of the footer here.
  #
  config.footer = 'Labguru Academy Admin Version 2.1 - Ability to mark lesson as new'

  # == Sorting
  #
  # By default ActiveAdmin::OrderClause is used for sorting logic
  # You can inherit it with own class and inject it for all resources
  #
  # config.order_clause = MyOrderClause
  AppConfig = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'config.yml'))[Rails.env]
end
```

Comment: Any error logs from the server? Sure thing that there must be happening something.

Comment: HTTP error 500 in production

Comment: Can you provide the error log?

Comment: I edited the question and added picture of the error and log in console

Comment: @OfirSasson We need a server log, not a console log

Comment: how do I get that?

Comment: ssh to the instance and find production.log

Comment: I tried but I have permission denied error even when I added the public key. I'll update if I have any luck fixing this

Comment: Do you deploy via `git push heroku master`? Then you prob have also heroku toolbelt so you can use `heroku logs`.

Comment: I added the error server I got on the log in the original server. It's something with devise but I don't know what exactly

Comment: have you tried running it locally in production with `rails server -e production`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding in production.rb this line:

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'my website url' }